# Highlight dates in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How i can use **beforeShowDay** for highlighting days in jQuery UI datepicker. I have the following date array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011-07-07
    [1] => 2011-07-08
    [2] => 2011-07-09
    [3] => 2011-07-10
    [4] => 2011-07-11
    [5] => 2011-07-12
    [6] => 2011-07-13
)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: i want to highlight the above dates.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved the issue using

```
var disabledDays = ["2011-7-21","2011-7-24","2011-7-27","2011-7-28"];
var date = new Date();
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $( "#dateselector").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
            for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,disabledDays) != -1) {
                    //return [false];
                    return [true, 'ui-state-active', ''];
                }
            }
            return [true];

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: +1, other option needed: Adding a link to the activated date to go to event description for example

Comment: You can avoid those y, m and d variables if you compare dates  getting their values before and using the counter i: if (date.valueOf() == disabledDays[i].valueOf()) { ...

Comment: @Nisanth: Your answer is doing an unnecessary loop. You don't need to do `for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {` because you're already doing `$.inArray`.

Answer (score 34):

Have a look at the documentation.

> [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) The function takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable, [1] equal to a CSS class name(s) or '' for the default presentation, and [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date. It is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

This means that you need to create a function that will take a date and return an array of parameters where values are:

1. boolean - indicates if date can be selected
2. string - name of the css class that will be aplied to the date
3. string - an optional popup tooltip for this date

here is an example:

```
var your_dates = [new Date(2011, 7, 7),new Date(2011, 7, 8)]; // just some dates.

$('#whatever').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      // check if date is in your array of dates
      if($.inArray(date, your_dates)) {
         // if it is return the following.
         return [true, 'css-class-to-highlight', 'tooltip text'];
      } else {
         // default
         return [true, '', ''];
      }
   }
});
```

and now you can add the style to highlight the date

```
<style>
   .css-class-to-highlight{
       background-color: #ff0;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: could you make a fiddle with demo, please?

Comment: I dont think you can compare dates like that in JS. `new Date(1) == new Date(1) is false`

Comment: I tried your code to highlight dates. But it isn't working with the dynamic array. However it is working the way you described. Any ideas? It is highlighting all the dates on the calendar.

Answer (score 3):

Found the most voted answer not working. Updated the code little bit to make it working. $.inArray() mostly search for indexOf(). Also we can't compare two dates directly for equality. 
Reference : [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

```
function inArrayDates(needle, haystack){
    var found = 0;
    for (var i=0, len=haystack.length;i<len;i++) {
        if (haystack[i].getTime() == needle.getTime()) return i;
            found++;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

And update the accepted function as

```
if(inArrayDates(date, markDates) != -1) {
            return [true, 'selected-highlight', 'tooltip here'];
          } else {
             return [true, '', ''];
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates in JS are instances of object `Date`, so you can't check properly if dates are equal using `==` or `===`.

Simple solution:

```
var your_dates = [
   new Date(2017, 4, 25),
   new Date(2017, 4, 23)
];

$( "#some_selector" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        are_dates_equal = d => d.getTime() === date.getTime();
        if(your_dates.some(are_dates_equal)) {
            return [true, 'ui-state-active', ''];
        }
        return [true, '', ''];
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a simple solution where only we have to give the dates which will be disabled and to show color for available dates.And it worked for me

```
   <style>
    .availabledate a {
         background-color: #07ea69 !important;
         background-image :none !important;
         color: #ffffff !important;
     }
     </style>
```

And for script use this:

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        //This array containes all the disabled array
          datesToBeDisabled = ["2019-03-25", "2019-03-28"];

            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              minDate : 0,
              todayHighlight: 1,
              beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var dateStr = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                if(dateStr){
                  return [datesToBeDisabled.indexOf(dateStr) == -1,"availabledate"];
                }else{
                  return [datesToBeDisabled.indexOf(dateStr) == -1,""];
                }

              },

            });


    });

  </script>
```

Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay

You compare the date parameter in the beforeShowDay with the dates you have got in your array, and if there is a match you return an array as defined in the link above.

In the array you return from beforeShowDay, the second element is used to set the class name which will be used on the date, you can then use css to set styles for that class.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use the builtin jqueryui function `formatDate();` When it comes to the css I had to tweak it a little and add extra classes to be able to highlight dates.

**style.css**

```
#datepicker .event-highlight .ui-state-highlight, 
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, 
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight 
{
    background-color: darkgreen !important;
    color : white !important;
    border: 1px solid darkgreen !important;
    border-color: darkgreen !important;

}
```

**jquery formatDate()**

```
//different date formats accepted
"mm/dd/yy"
"yy-mm-dd"
"d M, y"
"d MM, y"
"DD, d MM, yy"
"'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy"

//return today's date
$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate"));
    
//alternatively you can use this syntax
jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', 'getDate');
```

**highlight dates in datepicker**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
beforeShowDay : function (date){
json.events.forEach(function (jsondate,counter) {

//get jquery date
var jquerydate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date);

//OR alternative syntax
var jquerydate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

//get date busy with events
var busyday = jsondate.date;

if (jquerydate === busyday) {
return [true, '.event-highlight', 'tooltip text'];
           
}else{
return [true, '', ''];
}

});
return [true];
},
```