# How the jquery Datepicker set some date to highlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm use jquery Datepicker [link:http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker] now,and if I want Set some date to highlight, not just highlight the date now, how can I set the option?

For example:
[image]

There I want 24/09/2011, 25/09/2011 and 27/09/2011 to highlight.

Comment: Seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385332/jquery-datepicker-highlight-dates

Comment: thanks, I found better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857025/highlight-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: [This discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_thread/thread/5500b46e83d41bc1/6927a39ce0a01625) covers it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use the `beforeShowDay` option:

```
var dates = []; // array of the dates you want to highlight, stored as strings

$('selector').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if ($.inArray(date.toString(), dates) != -1) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
});
```

See this question for more information:

[Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida)

Comment: The param dates, can I defined it as <code> [new Date(2011, 8, 7),new Date(2011, 8, 20)];</code> and <code> if ($.inArray(date, dates) != -1) </code>.

Comment: @Shamrocker - Nope. In JavaScript, objects are compared by reference.  For example `{a:'a'} == {a:'a'}` will return false. To compare your dates, you gave to convert them to strings. Use this: `[(new Date(2011, 8, 7)).toString(), (new Date(2011, 8, 20)).toString];` and `if ($.inArray(date.toString(), dates) != -1)`.