# Highlight selected date in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a requirement to highlight selected dates. Lets say if you choose 09/20/2013 from first input then when you click on next input then 09/20/2013 should be highlighted. for reference http://www.expedia.co.in/. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj4Ry/2/)

**HTMl**

```
<input class="datepicker" id="depart">    
<input class="datepicker" id="return">
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".datepicker" ).datepicker(
{
numberOfMonths: 2,
onSelect:function(dateStr){
}});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How the jquery Datepicker set some date to highlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523653/how-the-jquery-datepicker-set-some-date-to-highlight)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dp1 = [];
$("#depart").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: "m/dd/yy",
    onSelect: function (d) {
        dp1 = [];
        dp1.push(d);
    }
});
$("#return").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: "m/dd/yy",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        dmy = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, dp1) >= 0) {
            return [true, "foo"];
        } else {
            return [true, ""];
        }
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wj4Ry/5/)**

The first datepicker pushes the selected date onto an array which the second datepicker uses via the beforeShowDay method to determine what cell to apply a class to.

Comment: Hi it is very close to requirement. I found two bug in this code one is year is feeling twice in second input and the second one is when you fill both input with date and again click on first input the selected date should be highlighted

Comment: I updated the code and answer to fix the double year issue, but I'm not sure I understand your second point. Are you saying that after picking the second (return) date that you want the same highlighting on the first datepicker (depart)? If so, is this what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wj4Ry/6/?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `beforeShow' event to set the date.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wj4Ry/3/)

```
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(
     {numberOfMonths: 2,
      beforeShow:function(){
          $('#return').val($('#depart').val());
      }}
 );
```

Comment: I dont wana set date in input, I just want to highlight date which we selected