# How to highlight a particular date in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I am currently doing project on task reminder where user can enter tasks for certain dates.For overview of user's task i am using jquery ui datepicker(inline).I just want to highlight all those dates given by the user.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-highlight-multiple-days-in-datepicker-in-inline

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight dates in jquery UI datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857025/highlight-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(d) {
            var a = new Date(2012, 3, 10); // April 10, 2012
            var b = new Date(2012, 3, 20); // April 20, 2012
            return [true, a <= d && d <= b ? "my-class" : ""];
        }
    });
});
```

here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qaEuj/

See this answer: [Highlight dates in jquery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857025/highlight-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)